# Running / Porting Mac apps

Tags: mac, porting

I recently wanted to install some software, but couldn't, because it only had a windows and a mac version (no, wine doesn't work on it). My question now is: Can i port the mac version (i dont care if its hard, id even do it if i had to recompile the whole thing (decompile, then recompile. Its not open source)) or something like that? Mac is relatively similar in the way it operates and runs on an extremely similar kernel, so kernel-wise, it should work, i just don't know how to install a .pkg file. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Im currently extracting the pkg file and examining its structure... If i can find a way to run them, i will add it here for other people who find this.

Comment: Most of what you seem to want to know is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093123/run-pkg-files-in-linux

Comment: There are some general guides to using `Darling` or creating a VM to run Mac stuff.  I've never had any luck at it although I did once manager to get an OSX VM running.  [https://www.maketecheasier.com/run-mac-apps-on-linux/](https://www.maketecheasier.com/run-mac-apps-on-linux/)

Comment: Ill try those out, and tell you the results in a few hours.